# How to filter Json in Ionic3

Tags: json, gridview, ionic3

i have a list of customers in ionic3 which has data like ID,Name,Amount.
my requirement is like when user input amount list should be filtered like amount greater then entered amount.[image]

Comment: can please add the code here .so i can help u

Comment: @kevalnayak  its done. Thanks a lot